# Getting nil class error in my rails app

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to pull images from the instagram API in my rails app and am currently getting an error:

```
undefined local variable or method 'search'
```

**My view**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <% search.each do |instagram| %>
            <%= image_tag instagram.images.low_resolution.url %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
```

**My controller**

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    access_token = "hidden"
    client = Instagram.client(access_token: access_token)
    default_search = client.tag_search('travel')
    search_query = client.tag_search(params[:q])

   if params[:q]
        search_query = client.tag_search(params[:q])
        @tag = search_query.present? ? search_query : default_search
    else
      @tag = tag.first.name
      @search = client.tag_recent_media(@tag)
  end

end
  def about
  end
end
```

Comment: The error is in your view. Where is `search` defined?

Comment: Shouldn't `search` in your view be `@tag` ?

Comment: yes the error is in my view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

In view

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <% @search.each do |instagram| %>
      <%= image_tag instagram.images.low_resolution.url %>
     <% end %>
  </div> 
</div>
```

In **controller**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    access_token = "hidden"
    client = Instagram.client(access_token: access_token)
    default_search = client.tag_search('travel')
    search_query = client.tag_search(params[:q])
    if params[:q]
     search_query = client.tag_search(params[:q])
     @tag = search_query.present? ? search_query : default_search
     @search = client.tag_recent_media(@tag)
    else
      @tag = default_search.first.name
      @search = client.tag_recent_media(@tag)
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: i think if params[:q] in not present then the value of `@tag = default_search` right?

Comment: Correct that's what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: please paste result of `default_search` variable and i have updated my answer please try that too

Answer (score 0):

search is never defined in your controller... I'm thinking you meant @tag since this is defined in your controller and probably meant for your view?

Try changing your view to this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% @tag.each do |instagram| %>
        <%= image_tag instagram.images.low_resolution.url %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: please come back to your original controller and understand that a variable that starts with `@` (i.e: `@tag`) and a variable that starts without (i.e: `tag`) are both different variables.

Comment: I now see that unfortunately still confusws

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    access_token = "token"
    client = Instagram.client(access_token: access_token)
    default_search = client.tag_search('travel')


    if params[:q] 
      search_query = client.tag_search(params[:q])
      @tag = search_query.present? ? search_query : default_search

    else 
      @tag = default_search 
    end

    @tag = @tag.first.name
    @search = client.tag_recent_media(@tag)



  end

  def about
  end

end
```